# select, avg statement not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table called Employee with about 17 different columns on it. One of those columns is called age. I am suppose to write up a statement that will get the average age of all the employees with an AS in the statement. Here is the statement I have written up and unfortunately I continue to get an error message. Also, I am new at this so please don't beat me to hard...lol.

```
SELECT AVG(Age) AS Average_Age FROM Employee
```

I get below error..

> msg 8117, state 16, line 1 invalid syntax for operand avg.

I believe the message is telling me that the avg is trying to calculate, but cannot do it.

Why did I see this done on a youtube video and it work perfectly for the person who created it? While I did the same exact statement I got it wrong...can someone explain that?

**Update as Per comments:**

Error Message:

> Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator.

Comment: what datatype is age?

Comment: @IanKenney regardless of the datatype, the query as written shouldn't give a syntax error

Comment: Um I hope I answer this correctly NULL

Comment: @JeffChambers not even close. Is this the **whole** query?, is `Employee` an actual table or is it a view?

Comment: Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator. <--- that is the error I continue to get

Comment: @lamak : from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177677.aspx avg requires an exact numeric or approximate numeric data type

Comment: @Lamak...yes Employee is an actual table that I created with about 17 different columns

Comment: Jeff, but now you changed your error message, so it is about the data type as @Ian said

Comment: @IanKenney I know that it requires a numeric data type, but op posted an error message that was about syntax (and now posted a comment that error is about the datatype)

Comment: Lets say the values were cat and dog - what do you think the avg should be?

Comment: @Paparazzi a very loyal cat?

Comment: ??? not sure on that one

Comment: @JeffChambers The point is that you chose varchar for the `Age` column, why?. If you have strings, how can you average them? (that's what Paparazzi was talking about, and the answer is, you can't)

Comment: @IanKenney posted a completely reasonable solution, it needs to be marked as the answer by the submitter who may or may not have deleted their SO account at this point because I get no returns when I use @"Jeff Chambers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If age is a varchar column you can try

```
SELECT AVG(cast(Age as int)) AS Average_Age FROM Employee
```

( but you may want to think about changing the datatype )

Comment: Ian, thank you. I will try this and see what are the results. It will take a while. I do appreciate you taking the time out to answer me. Just new to SQL and sometimes it gets very frustrating not knowing what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Personally I prefer using TRY_CONVERT as opposed to CAST if using SQL Server 2012 or later to let the system gracefully handle conversion errors. That also depends on if you are okay with NULL values when conversion fails or if you need to know that it is failing by halting the process.

Comment: Ian, appreciate the help on this it worked like a charm.

Comment: Now I understand what you guys mean when asking what is the datatype. I didn't know i could go into the design of the table and change it to money or int or smallint.