# Operand data type varchar(max) is invalid for avg operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

Can someone help me with this error?

```
SELECT 
   a.id, a.name, a.Report, b.Agentid, 
   count(distinct b.pyID), 
   count(distinct b.SourceID), 
   AVG(b.ChatDurationMinute) 
from table_1 a 
left join table_b b on a.id = b.agentid 
where 
   StartChatTime >= ''20200701'' and 
   LastChatTime <= ''20200831''  
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.Report, b.AgentID
```

And getting error like this:

> Operand data type varchar(max) is invalid for avg operator.

What should I do? Thanks to anyone who helps me.

Comment: The proper solution is to store your numbers in a numeric datatype...

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column? You should never do that

Comment: This is pretty much the same as your previous question... for which you already obtained an answer... what more don't you understand about converting varchar to numeric, and handling the issues that arise due to using the incorrect datatype?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select, avg statement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776547/select-avg-statement-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the naming conventions in the queries, it is very reasonable to assume that `StartChatTime` and `LastChatTime` are in `b` and not `a`.  If so, then the `WHERE` clause is turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

In addition, including `b.AgentId` in the `GROUP BY` is redundant, because the `ON` clause specifies that it should be the same as `a.id`.

Storing numbers in strings is a bad, bad design.  But you should probably use one of the `try_()` functions if you are stuck with a bad, bad design.

Let me assume that `ChatDurationMinute` is an integer.  Then:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.Report
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.pyID), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.SourceID), 
       AVG(TRY_CONVERT(int, b.ChatDurationMinute) * 1.0)
FROM table_1 a LEFT JOIN
     table_b b 
     ON a.id = b.agentid AND
        b.StartChatTime >= '20200701'' AND 
        b.LastChatTime <= '20200831'  
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.Report;
```

If those dates are really in `a`, then you can keep them in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ChatDurationMinute column's data type is varchar - so you need to convert it

```
SELECT 
   a.id, a.name, a.Report, b.Agentid, 
   count(distinct b.pyID), 
   count(distinct b.SourceID), 
   AVG(cast(b.ChatDurationMinute as float)) 
from table_1 a 
left join table_b b on a.id = b.agentid 
where 
   StartChatTime >= ''20200701'' and 
   LastChatTime <= ''20200831''  
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.Report, b.AgentID
```

Comment: i done convert to float but getting error like this: Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: @NamedJustin and that will be for the same reason as your previous question, some of the data won't be naturally converting to a numeric type. You need to post some sample data if you want further help.